# Distribuir valores em coluna, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou extraindo dados de uma tabela com a seguinte query:

```
SELECT
[nu-cpf] as CPF, [nome segurado] as NOME, '' as IdentificacaoCliente, 
'' as CodigoBeneficio, 
CONCAT([nu-ddd],[nu-telefone]) TelefoneResidencial,
'' as TelefoneCelular,'' as TelefoneAlternativo,cast([dt-nasc] as date) as
DataNascimento, '1' as unidade

FROM
mac_all
```

e preciso que a coluna 'unidade', a qual atribuo o valor '1' tenha, distribuídos igualmente, 4 valores - digamos, a título de exemplo os valores: 1,41,51,61.

Desta forma, se a minha query acima retornasse 100 linhas, a coluna "unidade" teria as 25 primeiras linhas com o valor '1', as 25 linhas subsequentes o valor '41', depois 51 e assim sucessivamente.

Se fossem apenas 2 valores, eu poderia usar a cláusula "top 50 percent", mas como são 4, desconheço maneiras de fazer isso funcionar. Existe alguma maneira de fazer no próprio código SQL? Ou preciso extrair os dados e fazer isso manualmente via excel, como tenho feito?

Comment: Nugo, a pergunta não está clara, sugiro exemplar com mais detalhes e tb compartilhar o código `sql`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, reformulei minha pergunta, acredito que tenha ficado mais clara agora!

Comment: Qual é o critério para ordenar o resultado da consulta, de modo a gerar valores para a coluna `unidade`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é o uso da função de classificação [NTILE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql) para dividir o resultado da consulta em blocos, numerando-os sequencialmente, e então associando cada valor a um bloco. Como exemplo foi utilizada a coluna `nu-cpf` como critério de ordenação.

```
-- código #1 v2
-- informe os valores a distribuir no resultado da consulta
declare @Valores table (Ordem int identity, Valor int);
INSERT into @Valores (Valor) values (1), (41), (51), (61);

-- calcula a quantidade de valores a distribuir
declare @QtdV int;
set @QtdV = (SELECT count(*) from @Valores);

--
with Consulta as (
SELECT [nu-cpf] as CPF, [nome segurado] as NOME, 
       '' as IdentificacaoCliente, '' as CodigoBeneficio, 
       CONCAT([nu-ddd],[nu-telefone]) as TelefoneResidencial,
       '' as TelefoneCelular,'' as TelefoneAlternativo,
       cast([dt-nasc] as date) as DataNascimento, 
       ntile(@QtdV) over (order by [nu-cpf]) as NBloco
  from mac_all 
)
SELECT CPF, NOME, IdentificacaoCliente, CodigoBeneficio,
       TelefoneResidencial, TelefoneCelular, TelefoneAlternativo,
       DataNascimento, V.Valor as unidade
  from Consulta as C
       inner join @Valores as V on V.Ordem = C.NBloco;
```

Na tabela @Valores devem ser informados os números que farão parte da coluna `ìdentidade`, na ordem em que devem ser distribuídos.